# Unable to draw motion paths of controllers

Tags: animation, armature

I am learning how to animate in Blender 2.83 and have been trying to get motion paths to work with not success.

If I select the hand controller of the rig and click on "Motion paths > Calculate...", all I can see is a cluster of points at the origin of the scene and numbers matching my frames.

[image]

These are the settings of my motion path

[image]

Is there anything I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Is the controller a bone? Are you sure that what you are selecting is actually animating and keyframed?

Comment: It looks like you are seeing the motion path for the robot object. Make sure the controller is selected as the active object, then update the motion paths.

Answer (score 3):

As of Blender 2.91, you can solve this by going to pose mode > select bone > select pose dropdown (as shown in the picture) > select motion paths.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to fix the issue for this particular animation, but I believe it was because the arm is in FK. I tried the same with the IK leg in a different animation and the motion path works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two Motion Paths panels, one in the Object Properties tab, and one in the Object Data Properties (Armature) tab.

Make sure you're using the **Object Data Properties** > Motion Paths panel when you have a ***bone*** selected.

The **Object Properties** > Motion Paths will draw the rig ***object's*** path, even in pose mode. Just be aware that there are two Motion Paths panels and that they look identical, but draw for different things.

[image: Object Properties > Motion Paths]

[image: Object Data Properties > Motion Paths]